# understanding pointers and casting in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I was given a function in assembly which basically converted uppercase letters to lowercase letters. Here is some of the assembly,

```
 Q1:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp 
    subq $24, %rsp
    movq %rdi, -24(%rbp)
    movl $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl $0. -8%(%rbp) 
    jmp .L2
L2:
    movl -4(%rbp) %edx
    movq -24(%rbp), %rax
    addq %rdx, %rax
    movzbl (%rax), %eax
    testb %al, %al
    jne .L4
    ...
```

Much of the rest is repetitive but L2 is what really is confusing me. This is my logic so far:
We store param1 into -24(%rbp). We create local1 and local2, set them both to 0 and then jump to L2. I move local1 into %edx, param1 into %rax. Now this is where things get confusing for me,
I was told the following line, addq ended up in local1 being a pointer to param1. I just reasoned add local1 + param1 and store them into %rax. How is that possible?

Next is, movzbl. From my understanding we dereference %rax so we get something like eax = (int) rax.

I was also told to think of it as converting a char to int. Which one is true, how do I know that I'm typecasting? What about if %rax didn't have parentheses around it? Is it an int because it's 4 bytes and %eax is a 32 bit register. Thank you in advance for your help, I'm kind of lost here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`local1` is not a pointer, it's an index (a counter).
That code is doing something like:

```
void toupper(char* text)
{
    int i = 0;  /* at rbp-4 */
    int j = 0;  /* unused, at rbp-8 */
    int ch;     /* in eax */
    while((ch = *(text + i)) != 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that in C pointer arithmetic `*(text + i)` is of course equivalent to `text[i]`.

Yes, the `movzbl` is converting an `unsigned char` to an `int` you can see that from the instruction name itself: **MOV**e **Z**ero extended **B**yte to **L**ong.

The parentheses denote pointer dereferencing.